# How to output the same column twice, effected by different WHERE clauses with the COUNT function

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2, ibm-data-studio

I need to output one column twice, under different conditions and aliases.
*Note: this column is also the PKEY of each table I pull from*

For simplicity, lets say the column i want to output twice is called COL1

-The first version of COL1 I want to output contains rows where COL1 is a unique value 
Lets call this "UniqueCol1"

-The second version of COL1 I want to output contains rows where COL1 occurs more than once in the data set
Lets call this "NonUniqueCol1"

The part of my query that's giving me trouble is that a bunch of other different conditions need to be true for each version of COL1, joins are involved, and I don't know exactly where to input the COUNT conditions that I believe I need.

The code I dropped below is essentially the query I have now.

```
Select T1.COL2, T1.COL3, count(T1.COL3) as Counted
FROM table1 T1
INNER JOIN table2 T2
ON T1.COL1 = T2.COL1
AND T1.COL2 = T2.COL2
AND T1.COL3 = T2.COL3
WHERE EXISTS 
(
Select 1 
FROM
table2 TT2
inner join table1 TT1
ON TT2.COL1 = TT1.COL1
WHERE TT2.COL4 ='A'
AND TT2.COL5 ='3'
AND TT2.COL6 <> '55555555'
AND TT1.COL7 = 'M'
AND TT2.COL2 = T1.COL2
AND TT2.COL3 = T1.COL3

)
Group BY T1.COL2, T1.COL3
HAVING count(T1.COL2) >=3;
```

The result of this query is something like this:

```
COL2      COL3       Counted
C0067     4355       3
D8120     5777       4
C4444     9009       3
TBC09     1133       3
C0999     4617       3
```

Out of those entries Counted in COL3, there are two different COL1's

1. The unique COL1 value
2. The COL1 value that shows up more than once

`My desired result is to print COL2, COL3, UniqueCOL1, and NonUniqueCOL1`

Thank you for reading, help would be so much appreciated as SQL is not my strong-suit.

Comment: *Sounds* like your after a conditional aggregate? For example `COUNT(CASE WHEN YourCol = 'YourValue' THEN 1 END)`

Comment: If I could put AND statements in those brackets then that may be what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you have explained what you are wanting to achieve very well, but here is some code that might help, or might not.

```
WITH table1(col1, col2, col3) AS (values ('x','a','a'), ('x','a','a'),('y','a','a'), ('z','a','a'),(null,'a','a'),('x','b','a'),('x','b','a'))
SELECT
    T1.COL2
,   T1.COL3
,   count(T1.COL1)          as NonUniqueCOL1
,   count(DISTINCT T1.COL1) as UniqueCOL1
FROM table1 T1
GROUP BY
    COL2, COL3
```

with returns

```
COL2 |COL3 |NONUNIQUECOL1 |UNIQUECOL1 |
-----|-----|--------------|-----------|
a    |a    |4             |3          |
b    |a    |2             |1          |
```